# start multiple terminal windows in a "process group" so that remaining processes can be killed, if any one of the processes terminates

Tags: shell-script, shell, process, kill, process-management

I have a script which starts 3 terminal emulator windows:

```
#!/bin/sh

terminator --role='terminator-left' 2>/dev/null &
sleep 0.1
terminator --role='terminator-center' 2>/dev/null &
sleep 0.1
terminator --role='terminator-right' 2>/dev/null &
```

(I am using the --role option, so that I can automatically place the windows on different monitors, defined in my openbox configuration file)

I start this script multiple times, on different virtual desktops.

How can I start these 3 terminals in some kind of a "process group", so that I can then kill all of the remaining processes, in case any one of the processes terminates?

Important: I don't want to kill all terminals that might have been launched in a different instance of my script (I cannot just use pkill or pgrep to kill any process matching a pattern)

So, in other words, lets say I launch my script on virtual desktop 1 and virtual desktop 2.

I have now 3 terminal windows on 2 different virtual desktops.

When I exit one terminal on virtual desktop 1, I would like the remaining 2 windows to automatically terminate, but without affecting the independent instance of 3 other windows running on my virtual desktop 2.

Is what I describe possible ?

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you have the `bash` shell?

Comment: @meuh - I do have bash installed, but I am using `zsh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer :**
I have had no opportunity to test my suggestion under openbox. I validated it under kde-plasma only,
My solution resorts on the `wait` shell internal command [as documented in the POSIX Programmers manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wait.1p.html). Some particular implementation could make the script simpler, using the -n option.

---

```
#!/bin/sh

ownkill()
{
        trap - CHLD
        pkill --signal 15 -P $$ 
}

terminator --role='terminator-left' 2>/dev/null &
sleep 0.1
terminator --role='terminator-center' 2>/dev/null &
sleep 0.1
terminator --role='terminator-right' 2>/dev/null &
trap ownkill CHLD
wait
```

This script is based on the idea to :

1. Launch the 3 *terminator* processes as desired,
2. Await for their completion,
3. Handle the SIGCHLD signalling the termination of one of
   the above processes in a way to terminate the remaining ones.

---

**Nota 1 (reseting the handler)** : As rightfully observed by aviro in comments, the signal handler must reset the handling of SIGCHLD to defaults since the killing of the remaining processes will trigger other (up to 2) SIGCHLD.
Failing to do so would force the shell in some sort of recursive  situation (the handler having to handle a signal it generated itself ) more or less gracefully managed depending on shell implementations. (from a harmless warning to some *maximum recursion depth exceeded* or equiv. error.)

**Nota 2 (Keep SIGCHLD default handling until wait)** : As rightfully observed by Martin Vegter in comments, the `trap ownkill CHLD` instruction is to be placed immediately before the wait instruction.
Placing it as the first instruction of the script (as I had absurdly suggested in a preceding version) would trigger the dedicated handler as soon as the first `sleep` process terminates.

Comment: In my case, Job Control is disabled in scripts so trapping CHLD won't work. For my trapping CHLD works only if I set "Monitor  mode" with `set -m` or `set -o monitor`. Not sure how it works for you. Anyway, the warning is shown because the `pkill` command also triggers a SIGCHLD when it ends. You'll need to reset the trap for CHLD inside the `ownkill` function before `pkill`.

Comment: @MC68020 - thank you, but it does not work!. I get: `Maximum function recursion depth (1000) reached`

Comment: @aviro : You are absolutely correct regarding the need to reset trap handling of CHLD inside the local handler. I stand corrected. Thanks. Still investigating about job control related issues though. Does not seem causing any trouble in my case.

Comment: @MartinVegter : OMG ! I see in some comment you are in fact using ksh. (which might get a different interpretation of $$ if I recall correctly). Will investigate & workaround.

Comment: @MC68020 - no, no. I am using `/bin/dash` as `/bin/sh`

Comment: @MC68020 - now after the edit, I no longer get the "recursion reached" error. However, for the script to work as intended, I had to move the `trap ownkill CHLD`  to the end, before `wait`. Is that what you intended ?

Comment: @MC68020 - so with the change mentioned above, the script seems to work exactly as I wanted. I just don't understand the logic why it works, and how you intended it to work in your version of the script. I would be happy to accept your answer, if you could briefly explain the logic. thank you

Comment: @MartinVegter : My bad ! So sorry ! I had indeed successfully tested my script in my own environment (with another process not requesting to sleep in between two launches!)… of course, as you rightfully observe… with the sleep instructions my solution just don't work since… the first sleep terminating will trigger a SIGCHLD ! I updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash, you can simply collect all the process ids, and wait at
the end so that when any process exits (bash's `wait -n`),
then all the ids are killed with some suitable signal:

```
#!/bin/bash
terminator --role='terminator-left' 2>/dev/null &
pid1=$!
sleep 0.1
terminator --role='terminator-center' 2>/dev/null &
pid2=$!
sleep 0.1
terminator --role='terminator-right' 2>/dev/null &
pid3=$!
wait -n
kill -hup $pid1 $pid2 $pid3 2>/dev/null
```

As one of the pids will already be dead, we redirect the `kill` stderr to null to avoid an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You might be open to using a systemd transient unit, as it is simple to start, control, and stop.
Assuming your shell script is, say, `./myscript`, add a `wait -n` command to the end of it so that is does not finish immediately, then you can start it with:

```
systemd-run --user --unit=mytest1 ./myscript
```

This command returns immediately with the message `Running as unit: mytest1.service`, and you can see what processes are running in the created
transient unit with the usual commands:

```
systemctl status --user mytest1
```

You can stop all the processes with one command:

```
systemctl stop --user mytest1
```

To run the same script several times, just ensure you use a different
`--unit=` name each time. If they all begin with `test`, then you can check
on them all, or stop them all by referring to them as `test*`.

See [man systemd-run](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd-run.1.html) for various options that might be useful, such as
`--setenv=`, `--working-directory=`, `--collect`, `--wait`. Note that you
can also pass arguments to your script at the end of the `systemd-run` command.

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand how the termination of one process would consequently  trigger the termination of others of the same unit.

Comment: I meant to say *add a `wait -n`*, not just a `wait`. This wait will return when any background process exits. This makes the script finish, and systemd kills the other processes in the control group as the unit stops.

Comment: @meuh - sorry, but I am not using `systemd`. I am using `sysvinit`. I did not specify this in my question, because I did not anticipate it would be relevant.

Comment: @meuh… is'nt wait -n exclusively bash ? (When apparently OP's scripts is sh ?)

Comment: @MC68020 yes, `wait -n` is not in all shells, but some systems link sh to bash and that  accepts `wait -n`, and otherwise bash is often available in distributions.